# Rounding issue when selecting with Eloquent Laravel 4 and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I just came across this issue:

Unittest on Laravel 4, Mysql DB:

**Code:**

```
$sql = 'SELECT 6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(-35.2712822))) as issue';
$laravel = DB::selectOne($sql);

$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=anydb;host=localhost','root', 'pw123');
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$pdo = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print "\r\nEloquent:\r\n";
print_r($laravel->issue);
print "\r\nPDO:\r\n";
print_r($pdo[0]['issue']);
```

**Output:**

```
Laravel:
3921.9876368885
PDO:
3921.987636888531
```

Any idea why that is ?

Comment: I copied your code and got the same result `3921.987636888531`